# Log4net dynamically name xml file, store and use the path and name to append log.txt

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

I am using log4net to capture any error in a try catch block. like so:

```
      catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //theres been an error and xmlReceipt is not null
            if (xmlReceipt != null)
            {
                //Log the error
                Logger.Error(ex);
                //log the Receipt object to an xml file in App_Data/ReceiptXml
                Logger.Error(xmlReceipt);
                //Append log.txt, explain where the ReceiptXml can be found
                Logger.Error(string.Format("The Xml Receipt was written to {0}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XmlReceiptPath"]));

            }

            //theres been an error and xmlReceipt is null
            else
                Logger.Error(ex);
                Logger.Error("The Xml Receipt was empty so no document was written");                               

            throw;    

        }
```

What I am trying to achieve is, when an error is detected and the `xmlReceipt` object is not `null`, log the error in the log.txt, this can be appended so it grows over time. I then append the same log.txt with the path and then finally I wish to create an xml document using the `xmlReceipt` object. Ignore the `else`.

See below for the `web.config`, I have tried to dynamically create a new xml document each time with  a dynamic date within the name however what is actually happening is the xml document is created with the name Receipt.xml and no date and the xml inside also contains the stack trace.

Can anyone help me change the `web.config` so that it dynamically adds the date to the file name and does not include the stack trace, just the `xmlReceipt` object. If you could also advise how I can add the xml filepath with the dynamic date to the `IF` statement in the `string.Format` line that would be great because I could then advise in log.txt the exact name of the xml document that relates to the error log.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>

    <root>
      <level value="ERROR"/>
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="ReceiptXmlAppender" />
    </root>

    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
      <file value="App_Data/log.txt"/>
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ReceiptXmlAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >      
      <param name="File" value="App_Data/ReceiptXml/Receipt.xml"/>
      <param name="RollingStyle" value="Date"/>
      <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyy-MM-dd.\tx\t" />
      <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="false"/>
      <appendToFile value="false" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message %stackTrace%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

  </log4net>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="XmlReceiptPath" value="C:\Development\Payment\trunk\WebsiteFrontEnd\App_Data\ReceiptXml"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Why don't you just create the files in `App_Data/ReceiptXml` without using log4net? Then you have full control over the path and content of the file.